# How can I specify different versions of react in my react/react-native repo

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Two questions.

1. I currently have a react web app, using higher order components, and redux to manage state. I am using react version 15.6.1.

   I am now looking to create a react-native project. Since I am planning to integrate the react-native and the react codebase into the same repo, I am trying to figure out the best way to do this, specifically regarding the version of react.

   The latest version of react-native (0.53rc0) has a peer dependency on react 16.2.0.

   The react app breaks when I tried to upgrade to react v16 and I don't have time to do those fixes at this stage, so I am stuck with react 15.6.1 for a while longer. Does this mean I have to use an older version of react-native (looks like 0.42 supports react v15), or is there some other way in which I can use the latest version of react for react-native only, while keeping it in the same repo.
2. To clarify - the reason I want to keep it in the same repo, is because I already have higher order components, so in theory I just have to write the react-native components which will to my understanding then be called by the higher order component when running in the mobile app.

   If anyone has or knows of examples of repos on github where this has been done (combined react and react-native project), that would be great so that I can get an idea of what such a project would look like once done.

Comment: Unless you are doing something quirky with React, it should be relatively easy to upgrade to React 16. Not knowing your codebase, I would venture it's still the easiest way to get these projects to coexist would be to get them to the same React level

Comment: Reasoning being that you simply can't have two versions of the `react` dependency in the same package.json. You'll have to reorganize your codebase to two different directories with a shared directory.